# AsyncTask to refresh text on UI Components

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, runnable

I have an AsyncTask class inside my main activity. This class parses a JSON Object and then it sets the texts on some UI Components like TextViews, EditTexts etc. The problem is that when it sets the text on the first TextView then it stops. It will not give an error but the "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" exception which actually means that you cannot affect any UI components through the AsynTask. I read that this could be done through a Runnable thread but i am not familiar how this can be done in my code. Any suggestions will be more than welcomed!!Thank you all!!

```
public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // do stuff before posting data
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String postResponse = "";
            TextView txt_class = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_class);
            TextView v_points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_points);
            //EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
            try {
                // url where the data will be posted
                String postReceiverUrl = "http://server.com/Json/consumer.php";
                Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConsumerID", "52"));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                // Convert response to String
                //String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                // TEST
                postResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON Object
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(postResponse);
                // Get the JSONArray "Consumer"
                JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("Consumer");
                //List<String> detailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Creating the array that will hold the json items
                String[] info = new String[ja.length()];
                // Loop through all fields
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("userid");
                    String fname = c.getString("userfullname");
                    String tel1 = c.getString("tel1");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String county = c.getString("county");
                    String country = c.getString("country");
                    String rpoints = c.getString("RedeemPoints");
                    String level = c.getString("Level");
                    Log.v(TAG, "User ID: " + id + "\n"+ "Username: "+ fname + "\n"+ "Redeem points: "+rpoints + "\n"+ "Level: "+level);

                    txt_class.setText("Domotel "+ level+" Member");
                    v_points.setText("TestTestTest");
                }
                //Log.v(TAG, "Testing response: " +  postResponse);


            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return postResponse;
        }
```

Comment: @llias can you please paste your Activity Code as well

Comment: @Haider My activity code is very simple. Initializes the UI components and then calls the AsyncTask

Comment: You can update them in AsyncTask...just not in `doInBackground()` since that method runs on a background thread

Comment: @ codeMagic Thanks for your answer. I tried to do it in the onPostExecute()  but it only updates the first component. Where should i do it?

Comment: That is the proper way so you were doing something wrong. You would need to post a question with the code attempt of doing it in `onPostExecute()` and explain what is/isn't happening. All methods of AsyncTask run on the main thread **except** `doInBackground()`

Comment: The problem is that on the onPostExecute() i pass a variable called "postResponse". Can i send both "postResponse" and the strings as well?

Comment: Sure, you could pass a list of the variables or something similar

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to do that? A BIG THANKS!

Comment: There are too many ways. Just search how to pass a list, multiple values, use a member variable, etc... and find what works best for you. Then when you get stuck post a detailed question of the issue

Comment: @IliasS. don't update UI in background but on onPostExecute function

Comment: Thank you all! I'll try to implement your suggestions and see what comes up!

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your UI in the onPostExecute of your AsyncTask.

Comment: Tried that also. It will not update them and i've read that you cannot play with UI components through the AsyncTask...

Comment: onPostExecute runs on ui thread